# How to link a traits generic type to some other element in the implemented type

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I am trying to create a struct that contains a generic field which is type-specified based on another field. This type is to be one of several structs I have defined.

Essentially what I am trying to do here is create a module which takes care of device configuration. This is meant to handle a bunch of different device types. Certain specifications will need to be configured for all devices and I have created a struct which, in an OO paradigm would be a parent class (here denoted as DeviceCfg). The device-type-specific specs would then represent child classes. (These are denoted as RaspberryPiCfg,Esp8266Cfg, ect).

I am trying to structure things such that I can reference a single object which merges both the generic specs (that apply to all devices) as well as the device-type-specific specs.

```
use std::net::{Ipv4Addr};
use std::any::Any;


//this struct is made to show the device-type-specific configurable items
struct RaspberryPiCfg {
    led_pin : u8,
    //GPIO pin connected to the LED strip pixels (must support PWM)
    led_freq_hz : u32,
    //LED signal frequency in Hz (usually 800kHz)
    led_dma : u8,
    //DMA channel used for generating PWM signal (try 5)
    brightness : u8,
    //Brightness of LED strip between 0 and 255"
    led_invert : bool,
    //Set True if using an inverting logic level converter
    software_gamma_correction : bool
    //Set to True because Raspberry Pi doesn't use hardware dithering
    }

//this creates a default function which sets all configurable items
impl Default for RaspberryPiCfg {
    fn default() -> RaspberryPiCfg {
        RaspberryPiCfg {
            led_pin : 18,
            led_freq_hz : 800_000,
            led_dma : 5,
            brightness : 255,
            led_invert : true,
            software_gamma_correction : true
        }
    }
}
 //this struct is made to show the device-type-specific configurable items
 struct Esp8266Cfg {
    udp_ip : Ipv4Addr,
    //IP address of the ESP8266. Must match IP in ws2812_controller.ino
    udp_port : u16,
    //Port number used for socket communication between Python and ESP8266"
    software_gamma_correction : bool
    //Set to True because Raspberry Pi doesn't use hardware dithering
}


//this creates a default function which sets all configurable items
impl Default for Esp8266Cfg {
   fn default() -> Esp8266Cfg {
        Esp8266Cfg {
            udp_ip : Ipv4use std::net::{Ipv4Addr};
            udp_port : 7777,
            software_gamma_correction : false
        }
    }
}
//this struct is made to show the device-type-specific configurable items
struct BlinkstickCfg {
    software_gamma_correction : bool
    //Set to True because BlinkstickCfg doesn't use hardware dithering
}


//this creates a default function which sets all configurable items
impl Default for BlinkstickCfg {
    fn default() -> BlinkstickCfg {
        BlinkstickCfg {
            software_gamma_correction : true
        }
    }
}

enum DeviceType {
    ESP8266,
    RASPBERRY_PI,
    BLINKSTICK
}

enum StatusType {
   ERROR,
   OK
}

//this struct is made to show the configurable items that are relevant
//for all devices
struct Devicecfg {
    use_gui : bool,
    //Whether or not to display a PyQtGraph GUI plot of visualization
    display_fps : bool,
    //Whether to display the FPS when running (can reduce performance)
    pixel_num : u8,
    //Number of pixels in the LED strip (must match ESP8266 firmware)
    gamma_table_path : String,
    //Location of the gamma correction table"
    mic_rate : u32,
    //Sampling frequency of the microphone in Hz
    fps : u8,
    //Desired refresh rate of the visualization (frames per second)
    min_led_fps : u32,
    //Frequencies below this value will be removed during audio processing
    max_led_fps : u32,
    //Frequencies above this value will be removed during audio processing
    device_type : DeviceType//,
    //device_cfg : T
}

//I am trying to create a trait to implement which I could use to create
//an object which when referenced represents the configuration of 
//both a devices device-type-specific specs and the specs that are not
//specific to the type of device being configured. 
trait DeviceSpec {
    type specs;
    fn setSpecs(&self);
}

impl DeviceSpec for Devicecfg {
    fn setSpecs(&self) {
        match self.device_type {
            DeviceType::ESP8266 => {
                self.specs = Esp8266Cfg::default();
            }
            DeviceType::RASPBERRY_PI => {
                self.specs = Ra\spberryPiCfg::default();
            }
            DeviceType::BLINKSTICK => {
                self.specs = BlinkstickCfg::default();
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Default for Devicecfg {
    fn default() -> Devicecfg {
        Devicecfg {
            use_gui : true,
            display_fps : true,
            pixel_num : 65,
            gamma_table_path : "directory".to_string(),
            mic_rate : 44_100,
            fps : 60,
            min_led_fps : 200,
            max_led_fps : 12_000,
            device_type : DeviceType::ESP8266,
            device_cfg : self.setSpecificCfg();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help. I'm still very much a learner in rust.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. A strong emphasis is placed on **minimal** (this is far too long) and **complete** (it's not valid Rust syntax, and does not produce the error you claim it does). Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Please also take some time in the future to investigate rustfmt and clippy, both of which will make your code more idiomatic.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `set_specs` instead, please.

Comment: I've read through your prose and code multiple times and I *still* don't know what you are asking. A hyper-focused MCVE is really going to help you out here (and in 99% of all programming questions in any context).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* you want to do something where the type of one thing depends on the value of another. This is going to be difficult or impossible in Rust. Types in Rust are only a compile time affair; you can't have a value of more than one type, or query a value for its type, or have a type that depends on a condition only known at runtime. You can do *some* reflection-ish stuff with `Any`, but I doubt that will solve your problem (whatever it is).

Comment: @Shepmaster I've tried to clarify things a bit, I'll go over again later when I have time but right now the rust-specific conventions might not match what I've used for vairable naming.

Comment: @trentcl that is kind of what I'm going for, but I get that is tough when things must be defined at compile time. Really I am just trying to come up with a way to reference an object that contains both the struct representing the configured specs which are specific to that type of device and also the specifications which are device agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Certain specifications will need to be configured for all devices and I have created a struct which, in an OO paradigm would be a parent class

Rust is not an object-oriented language, so it is bad idea to apply OO paradigms. There's no reason to use traits too. Rust traits are for defining common behavior, not common data.

I believe you should use composition instead of inheritance.

```rust
enum DeviceSpecificCfg {
    RaspberryPi(RaspberryPiCfg),
    Esp8266(Esp8266Cfg),
    // ...
}

struct Devicecfg {
    // common fields ...
    device_specific_cfg: DeviceSpecificCfg
}
```

Comment: *Rust is not an object-oriented language* — this is a hotly contested point, often depending on what you think "object-oriented" is. For example, **I** know that Rust is OO because you create objects that have associated data and methods. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming): *Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which may contain data, in the form of fields, often known as attributes; and code, in the form of procedures, often known as methods*

Comment: Just because Rust does not have **inheritance** does not make it non-OO.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is what I'm after. This discussion has been illuminating.